# RIGHT Joining table with query gives "Lost connection to MySQL server"

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
PRODUCT                                  ; STOCK_50644
  id product_name        category_id     ;    id   product_id               price
---- -------- ---------- --------------- ;  ---- --------- ----- --------------
   1 name1                             1 ;     1   2                           15
   2 name2                             2 ;
```

following query is working fine:

```
SELECT 

    c.id AS c_id, c.image AS category_image, b.id AS p_id, b.image AS product_image, 
    a.id AS product_id, 0 AS sc_id, 0 AS sub_category, 0 AS is_active2, a.*,b.*,c.* 

FROM stock_50644 a 
RIGHT JOIN product b ON a.product_id = b.id AND b.category = 1 
LEFT JOIN category c ON b.category = c.id 
WHERE b.id=1;
```

But if i replace `WHERE b.id=1;` to `LIMIT 1;`

Then it is taking forever time and then `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

## EDIT:

Tried

```
SELECT * FROM `product` p LEFT JOIN stock_50644 s ON p.id=s.product_id ORDER BY p.id LIMIT 1;
```

Still same problem taking forever time and then `Lost connection`

And

```
SELECT * FROM `product` p LEFT JOIN stock_50644 s ON p.id=s.product_id WHERE p.id=1;
```

is working fine

- Inner join is not giving me LEFT JOIN result in above query(idk why), Heres query:(`SELECT * FROM product p INNER JOIN stock_50644 s ON p.id=s.product_id ORDER BY p.id LIMIT 1;`)

Comment: RIGHT JOIN combined with LEFT JOIN?!?

Comment: a, b, and c are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, like p for product.

Comment: Any reason not to just `INNER JOIN`  a & b ?

Comment: Use `product LEFT JOIN stock_50644 LEFT JOIN category`. Move `b.category = 1` to WHERE. If you want to use LIMIT then define ORDER BY firstly.

Comment: @jarlh left with left gives the same problem

Comment: @LukStorms tried inner join. It doesn't work. `SELECT * FROM product p INNER JOIN stock_50644 s ORDER BY p.id;`   Same result taking forever time and then Lost Connection

Comment: @AnkitChaurasia  A join without `ON`/`USING` is just a CROSS JOIN that multiplies p with s.

Comment: *Still same problem taking forever time and then Lost connection* There is no ON clause - hence you have CROSS JOIN and too many rows for sorting. Use `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY p.id LIMIT 1) p INNER JOIN stock_50644 s ON {joining condition} ORDER BY p.id LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Yes You are correct my mistake. I have edited it out. But problem remains same

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result. [mcve].