# SQL/DJANGO query cannot make left JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

[Previous SQL Related Reference To my Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361510/right-joining-table-with-query-gives-lost-connection-to-mysql-server)

Heres My model.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'product'


class Stock(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_id')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stock_50644'
```

Im doing this simple query:

```
queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('stock__quantity')
print(len(queryset))
```

and getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`

When i `print(queryset.query)` Its always left join (product to stock) that getting stuck. What could possibly be problem here?

## EDIT:

###### print(queryset.query) :

```
SELECT `product`.`id`, `product`.`category`, `product`.`sub_category`, `product`.`group_id`, `product`.`product_name`, `product`.`is_prescription_needed`, `product`.`product_price`, `product`.`image`, `product`.`product_description`, `
product`.`product_keypoint`, `product`.`product_type`, `product`.`pack`, `product`.`pack_unit`, `product`.`expiry`, `product`.`hsn`, `product`.`gst`, `product`.`company`, `product`.`sku_code`, `product`.`brand_id`, `product`.`hospital_
id`, `product`.`distributor_id`, `product`.`distinguish_details`, `product`.`composition`, `product`.`drug_details`, `product`.`uses`, `product`.`side_effects`, `product`.`cope_side_effects`, `product`.`how_it_works`, `product`.`safety
_advice`, `product`.`what_if_forget`, `product`.`medical_constraints`, `product`.`created_at`, `product`.`created_by`, `product`.`modified_at`, `product`.`modified_by` FROM `product` LEFT OUTER JOIN `stock_50644` ON (`product`.`id` = `
stock_50644`.`product_id`) ORDER BY `stock_50644`.`quantity` ASC
```

Comment: Can you include the result of `print(queryset.query)`?

Comment: @FlipperPA Done. Please Check

Comment: You join 2 tables then sort this huge combined rowset. This needs too much time, and connection reaches the time limit. Select only really needed rows with according filtering condition(s).

Comment: @Akina `LIMIT 1;` and `ORDER BY p.id LIMIT 1` Both not working in my case. Thats what im looking for. But `WHERE p.id=1` works idk why this happening.  If above query is taking too much time then why `p.id=1` works and `LIMIT 1` not  works?

Comment: LIMIT is applied after ORDER BY is completed - i.e. it increases execution time. `p.id=1` decreases the amount of combined rows dramatically.